# Why isn't the delimeter \n being detected in C?

Tags: c, arrays, buffer, stdin, delimiter

The issue is detecting '\n' when I loop through my array. It works once as
shown in the comments, but it does not work after. The goal of this program is to take input from the terminal and put it into an array. The array should not contain any '\n'. Any help is appreciated, Thanks

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

// 1. Function must take input and place in array whilst making sure it does not overflow
// 2. Must return null if end of stdi is reached
// 3. Must ensure that it does not contain delimeter \n

// Tests:
// a) empty string
// b) string longer than buffer
// c) what happens when you press ctrl-d

char read_line(char *buf, size_t sz) {

        while(fgets(buf + strlen(buf), sz, stdin)){

                if (strlen(buf) < sz) {

                        if(buf[strlen(buf)-1] == '\n' ){
                                // IT GET'S DETECTED HERE WHEN THE ENTER 
                                // BUTTON 
                                // IS PRESSED BUT ...
                                break;
                        }
                }
        }

        // WHEN I LOOP THROUGH THE ARRAY IT GETS DETECTED AS SINGLE CHARS; '\' 
        // AND 'n' DISTINCTLY
        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(buf)-1; ++i){
                if(buf[i] == '\n'){
                        printf("present");
                } else {
                        printf("x");
                }
        }
        return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

        char arra[20];
        size_t sz = sizeof(arra);

        memset(arra, 0, sz);

        printf("Enter command: \n");
        read_line(arra, sz);

        // Print elements in array
        printf("Printing out array: \n");
        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(arra); ++i){
                char c = arra[i];
                printf("%c", c);
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you type \n into the terminal or did you hit enter?

Comment: I did both. For instance:

Comment: Hi there \n on whatever [then I hit enter]

Comment: Wait, so you typed a backslash, then the letter n, then you're surprised that the array has a backslash in it, then the letter n? Isn't that what it's supposed to do? Of course the array contains what you typed!

Comment: No,  the point it to detect that '\n' is in the array and if it is to print 'present' which it is not doing!

Comment: The problem is detecting '\n'; I managed to detect it when the user presses the Enter button, but when I loop through the array to check for '\n' (let's assume the user types "Hi there \n its me") it does not get detected as a single char but as separate char's

Comment: There's a difference between '\n' and '\\' followed by 'n'

Comment: `i < strlen(buf) - 1` ???!!!

Comment: Please elaborate, I'm very new to C; I understand but I'm not checking if buf[i] == '\\n' I am checking buf[i] == '\n'

Comment: When pressing enter it adds '\n' to the array. I want to exclude checking this since I know it is there, I want to check everything before

Comment: @Neumann `buf[i]` can only have one character in it. It can't have two characters. It can have a newline (which is written `'\n'` in C), but it can't have a backslash (written `'\\'` in C) and a letter n (written `'n'` in C) at the same time. When you check if it's `'\n'` you're checking if it's a newline. A backslash isn't a newline and the letter n isn't a newline so it never finds a newline.

Comment: This is where I am confused; buf[strlen(buf)-1] == '\n' worked but

Comment: in the for loop it doesn't

Comment: Well your for loop ignores the last character.

Comment: try `for(int i = 0; i < strlen(buf); ++i){` you will have better result... and RFTM of strlen ;)

Comment: http://rextester.com/KHHO91005

Comment: this expression: `strlen(buf)-1` will not detect a trailing newline because `strlen()` returns the offset to the trailing `'\0' (offset starts with 0)  suggest removing the `-1`

Comment: regarding: `char c = arra[i]; printf("%c", c);`  This would be better written as: `printf( "%c", arra[i] );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be entering something like the keystrokes <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

The entry of the two *distinct* characters `\` and `n` are *exactly* that, two distinct characters. That is vastly different to the single newline character which is represented in the source as `\n`.

In terms of what the buffer will hold, it'll be the string `"hello\\n\n"`, where `\\` is the `\` character, `n` is an `n`, and `\n` is the newline.

---

If your intent is to detect the newline in the string, you'll need to process *every* character in the string. The loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buf) - 1; ++i) ...
```

will basically skip the last character, which is fine for ignoring trailing newline should it exist but, if you want to detect it, you'll need:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buf); ++i) ...
```

Comment: This is the best answer, I didn't know the difference between \\n and \n, thank you for that. Also, I did know that it wouldn't include the trailing new line.

Comment: @Neumann well I don't understand a thing about your question so my bad

Comment: That's alright, I really appreciate everyone's help, means alot

Answer (score 0):

suggest replacing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(buf)-1; ++i){
    if(buf[i] == '\n'){
         printf("present");
    } else {
         printf("x");
}
```

with:

```
if( strchr( buf, '\n' ) )
{
    puts( "present" );
}

else
{
    puts( "x" );
}
```